# What is the best ( ie fast and small ) was to atomic_fetch_ptr and atomic_set_ptr on GCC linux

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

there are a bunch of fast memory barrier atomic ops in GCC linux like 
__sync_fetch_and_and etc.

I want to fetch and set a pointer value in memory so that it is guaranteed to be the value set when gotten as sometimes the assignment instructions are not atomic.  I don't want a heavyweight mutex for this as it is too fat.

what is the best way ?

Comment: I think the platform matters, too. I seem to recall some things were implemented differently or missing on Aarch64. Also see [GCC inline assembly and the removal of -mcx16](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2017-05/msg00187.html) on the GCC mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use atomic buildings in GCC. Use `std::atomic`, `std::atomic_compare_exchange_*` for your purposes. Google them on https://cppreference.com.

Information about what is the best you can learn in answers to the similar question [Which is more efficient, basic mutex lock or atomic integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15056237/)

Comment: sort of an answer :) why are the GCC intrinsics bad other than being compiler specific inline code?  I would think their implementation of std:atomic are templated wrappers around them.